disabling -rust-analyzer.log while running rust environments
in my current setup I use neovim as my editor with lsp rustaceanlsp integration(lazyvim).
Whenever I open a rust project a file called -rust-analyzer log is created in the PARENT directory.
I don't care about this file and now it seems like there is random instances of -rust-analyzer all over my file tree I cant get rid of. This is especially annoying to delete because for some reason there is a dash in the file name causing it to be interpreted as a flag.
Is there a way to disable logging with rust analyzer so this doesn't happen?

I mean you can find . -name -rust-analyzer -delete at the root. But rust-analyzer doesn't create that file for me to begin with. Maybe the RA_LOG_FILE or anything else in the logging section on github can help?
